# Error 87 in Authorize.Net payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net

I am trying to integrate Authorize.Net in WooCommerce, using the following plugin for it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-authorizenet-payment-gateway/

I set all user IdTransaction Key md5 Hash, but it gives me error 87, I don't understand where I need to put `x_market_type` as per the support document said.

This is the error I am getting:

Answer (score 2):

From the [Authorize.Net documentation about error code 87](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A597):

> **Response Reason Code**: 87
>
> **Response Reason Text**: Transactions of this market type cannot be
> processed on this system.
>
> **Notes**: The server is not configured to process the product type
> derived from the market type of this transaction.
>
> This can happen for four reasons:
>
> - You are attempting to process a type of transaction that your account
>   is not designed to process. For example, you attempt to use a card
>   swipe machine with an account that is enabled for Card Not Present
>   transactions.
> - Your software integration is passing an incorrect value
>   for the field x_market_type. If you are using a Retail account,
>   x_market_type should be set to a value of "2". The integration guide
>   for Card Present transactions can be found at
>   http://www.authorize.net/support/CP_guide.pdf.
> - Your Merchant Service
>   Provider may be incorrectly set up for this account.
> - The product type
>   (SIC code) is incorrect for this account.
>
> It is recommended to check
> the posting URL that is being used for your integration. Please
> consult the guide for the integration method you are using to verify
> the correct posting URL.
>
> To help troubleshoot this issue, you can confirm the Product Type for
> your account using the following steps:
>
> 1. Log in to your account at https://account.authorize.net.
> 2. Click Account from the main toolbar.
> 3. Click Merchant Profile.
> 4. Refer to the Product Type listed under Business Information.